# Java - iteration of an array list with case of no found

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I write this code who iterate an arraylist and if found a name who's equal to getName it's will print that and if not found will print "a message". My problem with this code is:

if a person have same nome of another persone the program will stop at first match because of break; how can i fix that?

```
import java.util.*;

public class AggPersone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<Item> voce = new ArrayList<Item>();

    voce.add(new Item("Robert", "Via qualcosa", "123"));
    voce.add(new Item("Roberto","Via qualcosina", "123"));
    voce.add(new Item("Robert", "Via qual ", "2222"));

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("chi cerchi?");
    String chiave = input.nextLine();

    int i = 0;
    while(i < voce.size()){
        if(voce.get(i).getNome().equals(chiave)){
            System.out.println(voce.get(i).toString());
            break;
        }

        i++;

        if(i == voce.size()){
            System.out.println("Nessun match");
        }
    }

    input.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Remove break statement in you loop it will print all of them ...

Comment: @StackFlowed: But you won't detect if none have been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to flag if the name has been found:

```
boolean found = false;
for (Item item : voce) {
    if(item.getNome().equals(chiave)){
        System.out.println(item.toString());
        found = true;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Nessun match");
}
```